# ASP.NET refreshing a iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

So I have a ASP.NET PDF web application that does PDF merging, splitting, and deletion of pages. I use a iframe to render these PDF pages.

What I want is whenever the user merges a document the new altered document will automatically show up on the iframe.

**Well the problem is that it isn't happening**. Whenever the user creates a new PDF document from merging it doesn't show up on the iframe, but instead a blank white page populats the iframe.

The HTML part of the iframe

```
<iframe src="DevContent\CAL_landing_page.pdf#zoom=50" id="outputPDF" runat="server" width="75%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

.

Below is what my PDF web application looks like.
If I was to press the "Merge" button I would want the new merged document that consist of A.pdf and B.pdf (mergedDocument1.pdf)to show up automatically on the iframe, but as you can see the iframe is blank.

If I press the "View" button next to the mergedDocument1.pdf then the merge document will show up correctly on the iframe, but I don't want the user to have to manually click the view button all the time after just merging it.
[image]

The code behind that manipulates the iframe

CODE FOR THE VIEW BUTTON

```
string fileLocation = "Data\\" + row.Cells[0].Text; // holds the PDF document location  
switch (e.CommandName)
            {
            //===========================================================================================
                case "View": // user clicked the 'view' button, the file in the row will now be shown to user in the iframe
                    outputPDF.Attributes["src"] = fileLocation; //
                    TextBox1.Text = fileLocation;
                    TextBox6.Text = (string)Session["pdfFileViewNameOnly"];
                    return;
```

CODE IN THE MERGE FUNCTION THAT DOESN'T REFRESH THE IFRAME

```
            // newMergedFile holds the location of the new merged pdf documents
            string newMergedFile;

            try
            {   // pdf document merges here and returns the string location of where the merge document is
                newMergedFile = mergeObj.mergeFiles((pdfFile)Session["mergePDF"], userFolder);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            };


            addAndRefreshGrid(newMergedFile); // adds merged document to the Grid view
                                              // allows user to click "View" or "Download" for the new document

             outputPDF.Attributes["src"] = newMergedFile; // show user the new merge document in the iframe, but doesnt work
```

When the user first uploads a file by clicking "Choose File" and then clicking "Upload File" the PDF document would populate the Gridview and automatically show up on the iframe correctly. The code below is a snippet of it.

```
 fileInView = @"Data\" + Session["UserName"].ToString() + "-" + FileUpload1.FileName;

 outputPDF.Attributes["src"] = fileInView;
```

I know I'm passing in the correct file location, because by simply clicking the "View" button it would correctly show up on the iframe. And as you can see from my merge function I use the same string variable to store it in grid and to attempt to refresh the iframe with it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try using developer tools' Network tab to see if the new 'src' of the IFrame is requested or not?

Comment: @OguzOzgul thanks for the quick input, I'm new to ASP.NET and web dev(Just started like 2-3 weeks ago). I just tried your suggestion and got    ```Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/PIA%20PDF%20Utility%20Web%20App/PDFutilityWebAPP/PIA%20PDF%20Utility%20Web%20Application/Data/-mergedDocument2.pdf"```seems to be a security issues from my quick research. Guess its back to the drawing board for me then.

Comment: can `outputPDF.Attributes["src"] = @"Data\" + newMergedFile;` in the MERGE FUNCTION be what you are looking for?

Comment: What I understand is, your client (browser) and server are both on your machine and you are saving the document to this location on the server then try to load it from the client from the same location. Your web app will not work when you deploy it on a different server and clients are requesting your server from their own desktops. You should have an HTTP Handler implementation to load the pdf file on the server and to serve it (by Response.WriteFile for example) to the client.

Comment: no that won't work ```(pdfFile)Session["mergePDF"]``` already adds the @"Data\" part to the newMergedFile string.

Comment: ```You should have an HTTP Handler implementation to load the pdf file on the server and to serve it (by Response.WriteFile for example) to the client.``` I don't know enough about this so I will be looking into this.

Comment: If the merged document is not loaded right after the merge operation, how come it can be loaded when the View button is clicked? It may not be a security issue at all, if you try to load the same URL (ile:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/PIA%20PDF%20Utility%20Web%20App/PDFutilityWebAPP/PIA%20PDF%20Utility%20Web%20Application/Data/-mergedDocument2.pdf) when the View button is clicked

Comment: Ok, an HttpHandler to download the generated PDF files is the correct approach. You should use the same approach for the uploaded files also. First upload the file to your server, save it somewhere (allow WRITE access to that location), always do everything server side, give the client a URL like http://myApp/pdfViewer.ashx (or .svc, or .axd whatever) and server the contents of the file from there.

Comment: To automatically download the merge document after a successful merge operation?

Comment: Yes, same for the merged document.